# EMR Spark - Unsatisfied link for libcrypto.so.1.0.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xgboost

I am trying to use xgboost4j with Spark 2.4. I have verified that the libcrypto.so.1.0.0 is present inside the /dev/so folder of the master and the worker nodes. The file was copied into /dev/so/ during cluster creation time through bootstrapping. I have also added the /dev/so/* to the spark.executor.extraLibraryPath and
spark.driver.extraClassPath. But when trying to train the model I am getting this error -

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /mnt3/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1583546919274_0001/container_1583546919274_0001_01_000034/tmp/libxgboost4j6574794715384475912.so: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does the libcrypto.so.1.0.0 file need to be in some specific directory? Any pointers would be of much help.

Comment: please post your complete spark submit here

Comment: I am trying to run a xgboost training from Zeppelin console not through spark-submit. Here is the spark.executor.extraLibraryPath property of my EMR cluster: 
/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/dev/so/*.   The .so file is present in the /dev/so path of the executor nodes which I have verified.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the error, that you may be using Zeppelin on Linux. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html explains how shared library loading typically happens. You can try installing `libssl` or update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (add your path to it).